# Creating a moment from different date formats and locales

Tags: javascript, date, locale, momentjs

Momentjs supports the creation of moments from an array of different time formats.

`moment("05/06/1995", ["MM/DD/YYYY", "DD/MM/YYYY"], 'en', true);`

This will create a moment on the 6th of May 1995. However, when provided with a locale that that uses DD/MM/YYYY as the preferred format i.e. `moment("05/06/1995", ["MM/DD/YYYY", "DD/MM/YYYY"], 'en-gb', true);` it still favours the first element in the array and creates the date for the 6th of May instead of the 5th of June. The second format is only ever used when the date fails to parse the first one such as `13/06/1995`.

Does moment support this functionality, how can I support multiple locales and formats and choose the right format based on the locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, create a moment using `moment("05/06/1995", "L", 'en-gb', true);` the multiple locale support provided by `L` will format to either `MM/DD/YYYY` or  `DD/MM/YYYY` depending on the locale which that moment has been created with.

Comment: You are mostly correct, however you cannot use strict mode (that last true) in this situation because that would require the separators to match, which they don't.

Comment: That is true, in the original question I copied the example from the the moment documentation. In my actual use case it is whatever is the `L` format of that locale is. So you're right; I need to change the original question.